# GitHub Pagesで公開したサイトの404ページを自作のものに変更したい

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

基本的な方法は公式にある通りで、
https://docs.github.com/ja/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site
つまり公開したルートディレクトリに404.htmlがあればそれを404ページとして利用するらしいです。
ですが私がreactで作成したサイトでは404.htmlを変更しても、404ページが変わらないのはどうしてなのでしょうという質問です。

ディレクトリ構成は基本的に react-create-appの `npm run build` コマンドで作ったbuildフォルダをdocsフォルダに名前を変えてGitHub Pagesでホスティングしています。具体的には以下のような構成になっています。ここに404.htmlがあれば良いはずなのですけど、何か読み落としているでしょうか。

```
root
-docs
---static
---404.html
---index.html
---その他..
-package.json
-その他...
```

Comment: この辺の記事が何か参考になるかも。[\[React\] GitHub Pagesにデプロイ](https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/react/github-pages/), [GitHub Pages で React Router を使った SPA サイトを動かす方法](https://maku.blog/p/9u8it5f/)

Comment: ちょうど一つ目の記事と同じようにやったはずなんですよねぇ